Wordpress-Imbed Variable URL based on search variable
In Wordpress, I’d like to have multiple imbedded URLs that are variable based on a user input. Outcome would be a top search bar that the user can type an input which would change the URL imbeds in the lower part of the page.
//For instance, the user types in the search bar:

XYZ = “Tacos”  

ImbedURL1= “search.yahoo.com/search?p=“XYZ

//to become the resulting Link

search.yahoo.com/search?p=Tacos

//I could have other imbeds so that someone could also search google for “Tacos” at the same time. 

Does this make sense?
I have been reading for different Wordpress plugins and if there is a custom block you would recommend I’ll take the recommendation. Thanks all.

Hi, Samuel Green and welcome to SO. Please include your effort in trying to create this. We will be able to help you with the code you've written. In any case, you would have to write your own system which stores the Tacos value in an object or associative array on submission. Then when searching a script should first check if the XYZ key exists, and if so, replace the XYZ in the string with Tacos.
